# Trying to create simple js minifier, but it doesn't remove anything, even though I delete the white space

Tags: c#, minify

I am trying to create a simple minifier because I am unsatisfied with the tools online. I have made a console application, but the problem is that nothing is removed, even though I split the text and remove /n and /t characters.

I've tried different methods of removing the whitespace.

```
static string restrictedSymbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,0123456789";
...
static void Compress(string command)
        {
            string[] commandParts = command.Split(' ');

            string text = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(commandParts[1]))
                {
                    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    text.Replace("\n", "");
                    text.Replace("\t", "");
                    string formattedText = text;

                    string[] splitText = text.Split(' ');
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < splitText.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        splitText[i].TrimStart();
                        StringBuilder tSB = new StringBuilder(splitText[i]);
                        if (splitText[i].Length > 1 && splitText[i + 1].Length > 1)
                        {
                            int textLength = splitText[i].Length - 1;

                            if (restrictedSymbols.Contains(splitText[i + 1][0]) && restrictedSymbols.Contains(splitText[i][textLength]))
                            {
                                tSB.Append(" ");
                            }
                        }

                        sb.Append(tSB.ToString());
                    }

                    sb.Append(splitText[splitText.Length - 1]);

                    text = sb.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }    
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            if (text != String.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter stream = File.CreateText(commandParts[2] + commandParts[3]))
                    {
                        stream.Write(text);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Process Complete...");
            GetCommand();
        }
```

It should print output a minified file, but it just outputs the same exact file that I put in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring any other problem, [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) by it self does nothing

> **Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with
>   another specified Unicode character or String.

So basically you are ignoring any changes by not keeping the return value

At minimum you will need to do something like this

```
text = text.Replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing the characters, but then doing nothing with it.

Your code should be:

```
text = text.Replace("\n", "");
text = text.Replace("\t", "");
```